# Apache Camel message multiplexer integration pattern

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to determine the best way to combine message streams from two hornetq broker instances into a single stream for processing, using Apache Camel and Spring. This is essentially the opposite of the Camel [reciepient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) pattern; but instead of one to many I need many to one. One idea is to implement this functionality with the [direct](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<beans xmlns="..."
       xmlns="...">

    <!-- JMS Connection 1 -->
    <bean id="jndiTemplate1" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                ...Connection 1 Specific Information...
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTopicConnectionFactory1" 
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate1"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</value> 
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jms1" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsTopicConnectionFactory1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- JMS Connection 2 -->
    <bean id="jndiTemplate2" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                ...Connection 2 Specific Information...
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTopicConnectionFactory2" 
          class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</value> 
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jms2" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsTopicConnectionFactory2"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Camel route many to 1 using direct component -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="hornetQ_broker_1">
            <from uri="jms1:topic:testTopic1">
            <to uri="direct:process_message">
        </route>
        <route id="hornetQ_broker_2">
            <from uri="jms2:topic:testTopic2">
            <to uri="direct:process_message">
        </route>
        <route id="message_processor">
            <from uri="direct:process_message">
            <log message="message_processor received message">
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

**Question: Is the above approach recommended when a many->1 integration pattern is required? If multiple Apache Camel solutions exist, what are the key performance impacts of each approach?**

Runtime environment:

- HornetQ brokers are JBoss EAP6.
- Camel context deployed to FuseSource 4.4.1
- Each entity exists on a seperate server/jvm.

Notes:

- The hornetQ broker instances cannot be clustered.
- The hornetQ broker instances do not contain duplicate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your approach is valid for your scenario. However, maybe direct is not the component you need to use for this if you are running in different JVMs.

There are different components for internal queues: Direct, Direct-VM, SEDA, VM, Disruptor... but I believe all of them are if you are running in the JVM (and some of the if you just running in the same CamelContext). For more info: [How do the direct, event, seda and vm endpoints compare](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-the-direct-event-seda-and-vm-endpoints-compare.html)

If you are going to have different CamelContexts across different JVM will need to use a different component.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In this case, the example spring config would be deployed to FuseSource and I believe all camel objects will execute under the same JVM. After reading the link you provided it seems like Direct and SEDA are the applicable components for this deployment type. Do you have input to the second part of the question, which in this case is considerations I should make when choosing between the synchronous (direct) and asynchronous (SEDA) behavior.

Comment: I would say it depends on the load you are expecting. But I would go for SEDA with multiple consumers. I have already used it with really good results.

Comment: So when expecting light message traffic, use the direct component; When expecting heavy traffic, use the SEDA component? Following the logic, jms1 and jms2 would each be a consumer (multiple consumers == expect heavy message traffic)?

Comment: SEDA uses multiple threads to handle messages which makes it more suitable for scenarios when you have heavy load o you are using big messages. I would not say that your statement is correct in every single situations, but it is most likely what I would do.

Comment: I see there is already a direct vs SEDA question on stack overflow, which may be of interest to anyone reading this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331886/back-to-basics-apache-camel-routes-and-direct-component