# How to trigger existing route in Apache Camel?

Tags: triggers, apache-camel

There is a route which read from SFTP after 30 Minutes

```
 public class ApplicationRoutesBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
                  "sftp://10.10.10.10/emp"
                + "?username=xxx"
                + "&password=yyy" // Stored on wildfly server
                + "&download=true" //Shall be read chunk by chunk to avoid heap space issues. Earlier download=true was used: 
                + "&useList=true"
                + "&stepwise=false"
                + "&disconnect=true"
                + "&passiveMode=true"
                + "&reconnectDelay=1800000"
                + "&bridgeErrorHandler=true"
                + "&delay=30000"
                //+ "&fileName=" + sftpFileName
                + "&include="+ sftpFileName
                + "&preMove=$simple{file:onlyname}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.processing"
                + "&move=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.success"
                + "&moveFailed=$simple{file:onlyname.noext}.$simple{date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh-mm-ss}.failed"
                + "&readLock=idempotent-changed"
                + "&idempotentRepository=#infinispan"
                + "&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true"

           //ROUTE IS
           from("ABOVE SFTP STRING")
            .onException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class)
                .onWhen(exchange -> { 
                        Throwable cause = exchange.getException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class).getCause();
                        return (cause != null && cause.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("2: No such file"));
                    })
                    .handled(true)
                    .logExhausted(true)
                    .logExhaustedMessageHistory(true)
                     // For troubleshooting. TODO: remove on final deploy
                     .log("Could not find file")
                    .end()
            .to(archiveReceivedFile(sftpFileName))
            .log("Archived Successfully in HRM Archive Directory")
            .bean("service1", "enrichFromAd")
            .log("Loaded IFS and AD Successfully into Memory")
            .split(body().tokenizeXML("EmploymentRequest", "EmploymentRequests")) // Split and tokenize the requests, streaming individual requests to message queue
            .unmarshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(EmploymentRequest.class)))
            .bean("service1", "updateEmployeeData")
            .marshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(EmploymentRequest.class)))
            .inOnly(EMPLOYEES_QUEUE)
                    .choice()
                    .when(header("CamelSplitComplete"))
                        .log("Download xml file completed");
```

I want to manually trigger this route. How can we do it using Apache Camel?

//As of now we are reloading or undeploying and deploying or restarting server to trigger route at load  or decrease time to 30 Seconds. But i do not want this. I can either create trig file or rename or may be trig using JSP page. But what code will trigg this thread?

Following is context initialization:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationCamelContext extends DefaultCamelContext {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ApplicationCamelContext.class.getName() );
    @PostConstruct
    void customize() {
        LOGGER.info("Started ApplicationCamelContext: customize");
        setName("employee-import");
        getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(2L);
        LOGGER.info("Shutdown ApplicationCamelContext: customize");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may make the route on-demand using [Content Enricher EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/content-enricher.html). Camel provides `enrich()` and `pollEnrich()` as  apart of Java DSL to implement it.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-ftp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/remote/SftpPollEnrichConsumeWithDisconnectAndDeleteTest.java#L71) is a unit test case that does pretty much the same thing. Using message delivery at an endpoint to trigger an `sftp` action.

On a side note, the example above uses a `vm:` component but you may use [`direct:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html), [`seda:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/seda-component.html) or [`vm:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/vm-component.html) components at the `from()` construct, based on your specific use case. Their differences are explained in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093307/what-is-the-difference-between-seda-vm-and-direct-in-apache-camel). I think `seda:` is the best fit in this specific case.

The route implementation should be like
`seda:trigger -> pollEnrich(sftp) -> rest of the processing`
Once this is ready, you may use a [ProducerTemplate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html) to deliver a message to `seda:trigger` to kickstart SFTP download. When to use the ProducerTemplate is totally upto you for implementation (trigger file/rest endpoint..)